# Get empty response (error 324) when memcached function fails

Tags: php, memcached, xampp

I'm using Xampp for ubuntu and my ubuntu version is 12.04LTS I installed php5-memcached, libmemcached and memcached php extension memcached-2.1.0 with pecl.

Memcached runs with no problems and I can use Memcached class in PHP but when a memcached function fails I get error 324 from my browser(chrome). As an example I wrote this simple php script:

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
var_dump($m->add('key','value'));
var_dump($m->get('key'));
?>
```

output is -> bool(true) string(5) "value"

Then i run it again (simply refreshing page) i expect output to be -> bool(false) string(5) "value"

but instead of it i get error 324 no response from server. I've looked php_error_log, acces_log, error_log nothing was written.

Thank you in advance.